# Swift 2 to Swift 3 Core Data in Xcode 9 - How can I port over existing Core Data "data" already saved?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I have an older project/app that I want to bring up to a 3.x version of Swift from Swift 2.  In the course of porting the code over I recreated a new project with the same bundle id to start fresh and imported the code over.

Everything is working now in Swift 3.2 in Xcode 9 except for Core Data.  Any device running an older version of the app crashes when accessing Core Data.

THe specific error is in the loading of the NSManagedObjectModel.

OLD SWIFT 2 WAY:

My CoreData File is called: "MyApp.xcdatamodeld"

```
lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("MyApp", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()
```

NEW SWIFT 3 WAY:

My new CoreData File is called: "MyApp.xcdatamodel"

```
lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
  if let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyApp", withExtension: "xcdatamodel") {
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
  } else {
    let modelURLOld = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyApp", withExtension: "momd")
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURLOld!)!
  }
}
```

When I run the code I get the following errors:

```
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/50367482-FC2C-4553-B04B-68AD922B8128/MyApp.app/MyApp.momd/MyApp.omo'

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSFetchRequest could not locate an NSEntityDescription for entity name 'UMyAppModel''
```

So my new app code is not finding the the files to load for CoreData.

How can I can load these older CoreData files into my app?  If need be I can set up a migration but the issue is that I can't see the older Core data files.

One way I can get the app to run is to add the following code:

```
  let objectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModel(from: [Bundle.main])
  return objectModel!
```

However none of the previous historical data is loaded into the app.

How can I migrate or get access to the original Coredata data to migrate into the new Coredata files on devices that have the old code version (swift 2) of the app?

Comment: Why are you attempting to load the `xcdatamodel`? That's not how it's done and is not required by Swift 3.

Comment: Yes you are right. I looked at some boiler plate code from a new coredata baseline project and added back to App Delegate. The problem is now the app is not seeing the old data.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. It was related to the way the NSPersistentContainer was being initialized in my app. The swift 3 boiler plate code was not migrating to the new data store nor looking for the old sqlite db (which I suspect was ultimately the main cause of the data not being found).

My code:

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
  let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyApp", withExtension: "momd")!
  let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyApp", managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!)

  let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask)
  let storeUrl = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("MyApp.sqlite")
  let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()

  description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
  description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true

  container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
  container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storeUrl)]

  container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
    if let error = error as NSError? {
      fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
  })
  return container
}()
```